object is not supported al usar OpenCV
intenté realizar un pequeño script de reconocimiento de color para reconocer casillas o contornos dentro de un juego y hacer click en el centro de ellas. Sé muy poco de python y OpenCV, y al ejecutar el script me muestra un error de formato no soportado. No encuentro el error.
La idea es crear una especie de archivo principal donde yo pueda reutilizar detectar_objetos(imagen, el color en HSV) en otros archivos, para no hacer todo de nuevo.
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import win32gui

def detectar_objetos(imagen, colores_hsv):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mascaras = []
    for color in colores_hsv:
        lower = np.array(color)
        upper = np.array(color)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        mascaras.append(mask)

    contornos = []
    for mask in mascaras:
        cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contornos.extend(cnts)

    for cnt in contornos:
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

        pyautogui.moveTo(cx, cy, duration=0.25)
        pyautogui.click()

        # print("Objeto encontrado en:", cx, cy)

def encontrar_ventana_runelite():
    for win in pyautogui.getAllWindows():
        if "Runelite" in win.title:
            return win
    return None

def capturar_pantalla_runelite(ventana):
    if ventana is None:
        return None
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(ventana.handle)
    x, y, w, h = win32gui.GetWindowRect(ventana.handle)
    return pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, w, h))

ventana_runelite = encontrar_ventana_runelite()
imagen = capturar_pantalla_runelite(ventana_runelite)
imagen = np.array(imagen)
imagen = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

detectar_objetos(imagen, (60, 100, 100))

Error en la consola
    imagen = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.10.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src data type = object is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'


Creo que ventana_runelite es None, y por eso capturar_pantalla_runelite(ventana_runelite) también, verifica eso con un print

Mady está casi seguro en lo cierto, numpy.array(None) genera un array unidimencional de tipo object (cualquier objeto de Python, como None), por eso el error src data type = object is not supported. Si encontrar_ventana_runelite retorna None no debes seguir con la ejecución y llamar a cv2.cvtColor, no tienes imagen que procesar...
